# Rails 3 + Docusign_rest how to send signature request to docusign

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, docusignapi

I Want to send signature request with docusign_rest gem. i have configure all the    things but i don't know how to perform next steps for signature request. how to get recipient id, email, subject and all. i have tried a lot but so confused in how to manage code.

please help me....

i am using docusign_rest gem and want to integrate its api in my code. i have all the credentials.

this is my controller

```
  class EmbedDocusignController < ApplicationController

   def embedded_signing
   end

   def docusign_response
     utility = DocusignRest::Utility.new

     if params[:event] == "signing_complete"
      flash[:notice] = "Thanks! Successfully signed"
      render :text => utility.breakout_path(some_path), content_type: :html
     else
      flash[:notice] = "You chose not to sign the document."
      render :text => utility.breakout_path(some_other_path), content_type: :html
     end
   end
   def get_envelope
     client = DocusignRest::Client.new
     document_envelope_response = client.create_envelope_from_document(
     email: {
       subject: "test email subject",
       body: "this is the email body and it's large!"
      },
     signers: [
      {
      embedded: false,
      name: 'Test Guy',
      email: 'my@yahoo.com',
      role_name: 'Issuer',
      sign_here_tabs: [
        {
          anchor_string: 'sign_here_1',
          anchor_x_offset: '140',
          anchor_y_offset: '8'
          }
         ]
       },
      ],
     file: [ {path: '/assets/doc/test.pdf', name: 'test.pdf'} ],
      status: 'sent'
     )
   end 
  end
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: if you want to move with docusign_rest its very simple really. ruby on rails provide great platform to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get a recipient id, instead you actually set and maintain that ID yourself.  So all you have to do is set the recipient id in your request body, add the recipient's email and name, and send the signature request.

To send a signature request through DocuSign's REST API you need to send an http POST request to the uri

```
/accounts/<accountId>/envelopes
```

One of the properties in your request body is the **status** property.  This has two potential values- *sent* or *created*.  If set to sent, then once you make this http request the envelope will be sent to its recipients immediately.  If you set the status to created then the envelope will be saved as a draft and you can send at a later time.

Try adding the recipientId property to your request, and set it simply to "1" and send.  That should get your signature request sent.  Also, DocuSign has a tutorial for getting started with signature requests - it uses PHP but the idea is the same.  Try using this as a base and integrating into your Ruby code:

http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/request-signatures

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply... m really getting confused with code.  m done with url as u mentioned and now i want to put request parameters so can u please tell me how could i perform next step??? that doc gives code but not mention where to put them in ruby on rails. so please tell me how can i improve it. do i have to make custom page to get recipient_name and email. and then pass as a arguments or parameter in code??

Comment: My url is : @url = "#{@client.endpoint}/accounts/#{session[:account_id]}/envelopes" ******   and when i put document_envelope_response = client.create_envelope_from_document(<ARGUMENTS>) this gives me error of ">>>>   undefined method `each_with_index' for nil:NilClass <<<<<"

Comment: How can i login call ??? and create_envelope after that. which parameters do i needed. and then how can i get access via http. please help me

Comment: Ergin: m passing method but it goes nil. why so? it is not passing any parameter in to file_io in built method. can u help me?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know Ruby to well so I can't answer your Ruby specific questions.  As mentioned above, it doesn't matter what language you use, as long as you send properly formatted http requests.  You need to setup your Ruby program to send a http POST request and have whatever body you are trying to send.  Hopefully some Ruby programmers can chime in and help here...

Comment: Ergin: thanks but i want to knw that y json request empty and why server send me a blank response? if you know about it then please help me. my request works but it shows me error of json as i mentioned above. why so? in other languages the same problem occurs while requesting?